# Jquery.js disabling the 'editable' function of bootstrap-editable.min.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, x-editable

I am working with x-editable. My page has a button that disable/enable the ***editable property of inputs***. Its working  perfect without using Jquery.js file..But my layout includes Jquery.js file and its not working and getting 'typeerror -editable() is not a function'. Without this jquery.js there is no error and its working fine.
how do i unload this js file from specific page?
  These are the scripts-

```
*<script id="js-file" src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.js"></script>*

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/x-editable/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/x-editable/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

**code of x-editable** :

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';   
    $('.container .editable').editable('toggleDisabled');
    $('#btnenable').on('click', function (e) {      
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        $('.container .editable').editable('toggleDisabled');          

    });
```

**removing js code:**

```
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype) {    

        var targetelement = (filetype == "js") ? "script" : (filetype == "css") ? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
        var targetattr = (filetype == "js") ? "src" : (filetype == "css") ? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
        var allsuspects = document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
        for (var i = allsuspects.length; i >= 0; i--) { //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
            if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr) != null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename) != -1)
                allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
        }
    }

removejscssfile("/Scripts/js/jquery.js", "js");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hurrah !! :) I found the answer myself:)

If there is any conflict between jquery occurs just write 
 *jQuery.noConflict();*

Comment: Where do I have to right this? I have the same problem.